# Simple circuit transfer function and output graph

Tags: diodes

I have this simple circuit and I need to graph the circuit transfer function and also graph the output as a function of time. The output is marked A-B and the source voltage is 10 V peak.

I know that when the source is between 0 and 5 V, the diode is polarized direct and the output is 0V. But I don't know what happens when the source is in the range of 5 to 10 V and 10 to 5 V

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simulator to get a time domain plot. This is a non-linear circuit, so you can't make a traditional transfer function (s domain).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY6SDf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The simulator doesn't have an ideal diode, but you can get close if you modify a few paramters. Make I_S and N much, much smaller, like 6 orders of magnitude smaller (can't be zero or the simulator complain when it tries to divide by zero). Make R_S zero. For this problem, the other parameters can be left at the default for a 1N4148.

[image]

[image]