# A conflicting result in the diode and capacitor circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, diodes

Consider following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4gilJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The question is determining output voltage.
D1 is an ideal diode with zero threshold voltage.

Certainly when input goes from zero to peak voltage the diode is off but the problem is after that time. Both on and off assumptions for the diode is valid when  $$T/4\le t\le T/2$$ If we assume diode is off then $$V_D = 0 - V_{out} = -V_1\lt 0$$ because $$T/4\le t\le T/2 \implies 0\le V_1\le V_{peak}$$
On the other hand assuming diode is on leads to $$ i_D = -C_1V_1' \gt 0 \implies V_1'\lt 0$$ which is true because $$V_1' = V_p\omega \cos{\omega t} \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ T/4\le t\le T/2$$
What is my mistake here? According to my book during entire positive half cycle diode is off but I don't know what's the problem with on state.

Comment: @DKNguyen i_D is the current of diode which goes from anode to cathode.

Comment: I'm talking about the passive sign convention in your second equation. Why is Vd=-Vout? I don't know what CV in your 4rth equation is supposed to be either. CV doesn't mean anything. Caps aren't resistors.

Comment: @DKNguyen $$V_D= V_{+} - V_{-} = 0 - V_{out}$$

Comment: @DKNguyen fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: What are V+ and V- supposed to be?

Comment: @DKNguyen They are the anode and cathode of the diode D1.

Comment: C1V1 is not what the capacitor equation is. i=C(dv/dt) for a capacitor

Comment: @DKNguyen You mean $$ i_D = -C_1\times \frac{dv_1}{dt}$$ is wrong?

Comment: Oh, you are using ' to mean derivative.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, that is right.

Comment: What polarity/direction are you defining positive Vd and positive Id to be?

Comment: @DKNguyen I added the direction of Id and $$V_D= V_{+} - V_{-}$$.

Comment: @DKNguyen In the first I assumed diode is off and then proved Vd<0.

Comment: hold on. I messed up

Comment: What is assumed polarity of C1 voltage? +- or -+?

Comment: Draw assumed voltage polarity of C1 like you did with D1 please

Comment: @DKNguyen I added that.

Comment: Thank you. At least part of the problem is you assume a voltage polarity counter to your assumed current flow. Assume ALL unknown voltage drop polarities as if they were loads or sources. Do not mix. In your case you assume D1 was a load but assumed C1 was a source. I am still looking at other problem...

Comment: @DKNguyen I don't think it changes the answer. If you try that your answer will be same and $$V_1' \lt 0$$

Comment: Hmmm I see your conundrum. I need to think. After KVL you have a 0=Vd-int(i/C)+V1 so you d/dt everything so you can isolate i. In that step did you go d(Vd1)/dt = 0? Vd1 is not a constant so you cannot do that. It is zero only when forward biased. When reverse biased it is nonzero so you can't just say d(Vd1)/dt=0 since Vd1 changes with time as V1 swings above and below 0V.

Comment: _"If we assume diode is off then..."_ - Why wouldn't it be? The diode was off so the capacitor got no charge and voltage is the same on both sides, therefore the diode stays off. Nothing changes until V1 goes _negative_, when the diode turns on and charges the capacitor.

Comment: @BruceAbbott For solving diode circuits, we always assume a state for diodes and continue. I assumed that diode is on and conclude $$ V_1' \lt 0$$ and because this is a true statement, assumption is true.The problem is that none of on or off assumptions doesn't lead us to a contradiction.

Comment: Why do you have the Cap polarity Reversed?   Work it out!! Fix it.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I think the polarity is arbitrarily. It doesn't change the answer.

Comment: It demonstrates a problem in your understanding besides real caps might complain loudly.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Okay but could you say please what's wrong about this circuit when the diode is on? What is the contradiction when we assume diode is on(I mean how KVL is contradicted)?

Comment: Your expression of the analysis is incomplete and flawed. Simply put Ic= CdV(t) when Vin(t) > Vc(t) with proper polarity.

Comment: Why you think 
V′1=Vpωcosωt <0   for  T/4≤t≤T/2 ? Isn't cosine is +ve in that interval?

Comment: @user215805 Note that cos(2pi*(1/T)*(T/4)) = cos(pi/2) = 0 and cos(2pi*(1/T)*(T/2)) = cos(pi) = -1.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is your on-state assumption, because it contradicts itself

See, according to the following statement:

$$i_D=−C_1V_1^′>0$$

It's assumed that \$i_D=−C_1V_1^′\$, meaning that the current flows from the cathode end to the anode end of the diode. Putting it simply, the \$i_D\$ arrow in your drawing is flipped. This assumption in itself is OK. It means that the calculated current will have an opposite direction.

The problem starts though with the second part of your assumption, i.e. \$i_D>0\$: This opposes the assumption that you just made (negative \$i_D\$). You cannot have both assumptions at the same time, because they just contradict each other.

The correct assumption  in this case would be

$$i_D=−C_1V_1^′ < 0 \rightarrow V_1^′>0$$

OR if you flip the \$i_D\$ arrow, you would have

$$i_D=C_1V_1^′>0 \rightarrow V_1^′>0$$

which is the same. Considering the derivative of the voltage across the capacitor:

$$V_1^′=V_p\omega \cos(\omega t)$$

Selecting a few time points, a frequency of \$100Hz\$ and \$C_1=1\mu F\$ (considering the original arrow direction) yields:

$$i_D(t=T/4)=-C_1\cdot V_p\omega \cos(\omega t)=-1\mu F\cdot 1V\cdot 2\pi 100Hz \cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0A$$

$$i_D(t=3T/8)=444\mu A$$

$$i_D(t=T/2)=628\mu A$$

***This can be double checked via simulation***

Simulating the on-state assumption (diode with no forward voltage and negligible off-resistance - otherwise no current could flow):

As you can see from the waveform, the current values match the calculated ones. In this case, the current is indeed flowing from the cathode to the anode, meaning that the assumption is correct.

[image: Circuit]

[image: waveform]

Comment: Why you are saying that \$i_D=−C_1V_1^′\$, means the current flows from the cathode end to the anode end of the diode?

Comment: When you analyze a circuit using KCL, you have to select a direction for the current. In your case the arrow is pointing upwards, meaning the current is flowing from the cathode to the anode side of the diode.

Comment: Yes, that's right. We choose a direction for the current but it can be positive or negative. Here we assume that diode is on and then choose a direction for iD(It doesn't mean iD > 0 necessarily). Using KVL $$i_D = -C_1V_1'$$ For the diode to be on means $$i_D \gt 0$$ so $$V_1' \lt 0$$.

Comment: This is contradictory. You cannot say at the same time \$i_D=-C_1V_1^′\$ and \$i_D>0\$. In the first assumption you say that the current flows from cathode to anode, meaning it is going to be negative. And in your second assumption you assume that it flows from anode to cathode (positive). Positive and negative refer to the direction of the \$i_D\$ arrow

Comment: After choosing a direction for iD and applying KVL we got that equation. No further assumptions was made for iD.

Comment: Indirectly a second assumption is made. By mentioning, that during \$T/4 \le t \le T/2 \$ the current \$i_D>0\$, it is implied that the current during this interval will be flowing from the anode to the cathode (positive current).

Answer (score 2):

The diode on/off trial method may not always work if there is a capacitor in the circuit, it could conduct for part of each cycle. But, for now, lets assume that it will work.

First, solve for steady-state only, don't worry about startup. At steady-state, the diode must be off, else the capacitor would charge to infinity (there is no other path for the diode current).

Next, recognize that the cap is a high-pass filter. Since there is no resistor (infinitely large), the cutoff frequency is infinitely low, it will pass everything but DC.

There is no current in the diode at steady-state (previously concluded), but the diode also won't let the output voltage go below zero.

High-pass filter, voltage never below zero: conclusion: sine, with bottom of sine at zero.

If you must know what happens for the first cycle(s), you need to analyze in pieces.

For  0 ≤ t ≤ T/2, diode is off.

For T/2 ≤ t ≤ 3T/4, diode is on, cap charges to Vpeak.

For 3T/4 ≤ t, diode is off.

Here is the answer using the simulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcraMQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I modified the diode parameters to make it close to perfect. You can see what I did in this answer. [Simple circuit transfer function and output graph](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483869/simple-circuit-transfer-function-and-output-graph/483875#483875)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you mention what's my mistake in the above analysis please?

Comment: The derivative of sine (cos) is only valid if the voltage across the cap is a sine. It won't be until the circuit reaches steady-state..

Comment: If we assume that diode is on then voltage across the cap is a sine.

Comment: Besides the steady-state issue, cosine is negative from T/4 to T/2, so current can't flow through the diode.

Comment: Yes, it's negative so i_D>0 because $$ i_D = -C_1V_1' \gt 0$$

Comment: OK, forget my last comment ( ... voltage across the cap is a sine), I had the sign wrong. You need to consider the pre-existing conditions. The diode was not conducting from T = 0 to T = T/4, so the cap never charged, so when the Vin slope goes negative, Vin is still positive, and Vout is positive also, no current can flow until T/2.

Comment: If we assume diode is off then Vd<0 as you said and so this is the case but the problem is that if we assume diode is on then we conclude dV1/dt<0 and this is also true for T/4<t<T/2.

Answer (score 2):

When you assume the diode states than you need to ensure that there are no contradictions in the resulting circuit configuration. By just looking at the I-V characteristics of diode it seems like the ON state is possible but the resulting circuit does not follow KVL.
For the current direction you assumed, the voltage drop across the loop is \$V_1 - V_c > 0\$, since \$V_c < 0\$.
There are no contradictions associated with the OFF state and hence it is the correct state.
**EDIT**
The circuit diagram on the left shows you the original circuit which is transformed to circuit on the right if diode is assumed to be on. For diode to be ON, the current has to flow in the indicated direction. This implies the capacitor plate connected to node \$V_{out}\$ will be positively charged by the current. Consequently, the voltage drop across the capacitor \$V_c\$, as indicated below, will be positive (I have reversed the polarity of \$V_c\$ from from what you indicated). Now, apply KVL in the A - B - \$V_{out}\$ - D loop:
$$0 + V_s + V_c + V_d = 0 \implies V_s + V_c = 0$$.
This is a contradiction since both \$V_s\$ and \$V_c\$ are positive as explained before.
But even before solving for these equations, you can see that if you have the circuit on the right the current will flow from the voltage source towards the ground not the other way around, which you indicated. Since diode does not allow such a current, it will be turned off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8Gk1k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why ON state does not follow KVL? Here is the main problem.

Comment: As I explained in the answer, the capacitor will be charged in the opposite polarity to what you depict in the figure. The potentials of voltage source and capacitor are going to add up giving non-zero potential drop across the loop because the diode is a short. This is the contradiction.

Comment: I think the reason is Vc(0+) = Vc(0-) = 0. Is this same as your answer?

Comment: No...hopefully the edit helps

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: **the assumption the diode is in forward mode is incorrect.**

> Certainly when input goes from zero to peak voltage the diode is off

Correct. No current flows through the capacitor and diode.
**Therefore \$V_{out}(t) = V_1(t)\$** for \$ 0 \le t\le T/4 \$.

> Both on and off assumptions for the diode is valid when  $$T/4\le t\le T/2$$

This statement is incorrect. As we saw above, at \$t = T/4\$ applies: \$V_{out}=V_1(T/4) = V_{peak} \$.
Therefore \$V_D=0-V_{peak}\$, so it is, or better, it *stays* reversed biased.
In other words, **only** *"the off assumption for the diode"* is true.

Note that
$$ i_D = -C\frac{d \Big(V_1(t)-Vout(t) \Big)}{dt} = 0 \neq -C_1V_1'$$

---

Note that when \$V_{out}(T/4)=0\$ were true, then the remainder of your elaboration is true (I inserted a part):

> $$ i_D = -C\frac{d \Big(V_1(t)-Vout(t) \Big)}{dt} = -C_1V_1' \gt 0 \implies V_1'\lt 0$$ which is true because $$V_1' = V_p\omega \cos{\omega t} \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ T/4\le t\le T/2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that is some inappropriate cases, you used V1 as the voltage across the cap.  In fact, isn't V1, it's V1-Vout

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand your answer. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Vout will be a sinewave with its negative going troughs peaking at 0V and its positive going peaks peaking at 2*root2*V1 where V1 is the RMS value of the voltage source.

The +ve and -ve signs on the cap are the wrong way around.